# What's the best way to create textures for an overlay system?

Tags: texturing, uv

I am trying to create a system where I can customise the look of a character by overlaying textures on top of a base body texture. For example, I can choose different eyes, mouths, scars, makeup, tattoos, etc. The way I am doing it now is by painting stencils of 2048x2048 images with high interpolation onto 2048x2048 textures so that I can get enough resolution in the areas of the texture that I am actually using, but it's a lot of wasted space and it uses too many resources if I want to overlay, say, 20 textures on top of each other.

My other idea to do this was to use multiple uv maps (one for the face, each arm, legs, etc.) so that I could get around the same quality while being able to use much smaller texture sizes, but it also makes it more difficult to work with and harder to create textures that run across multiple uv maps (like a tattoo that goes across the arm and torso uv map). I also had problems with textures mapping to the wrong spots because I couldn't figure out how to get rid of the parts of the uv map that I wasn't using other than shrinking them and moving them into a corner.

Just in case this has any importance, I am using three.js and glsl to implement the actual system.

I would really like to know the best way to go about this so that it isn't too computationally intensive to use. I also apologise if I've overlooked anything or gotten anything wrong, I have never done anything like this before and it has been a fairly large learning curve to even get a basic version of it working how I want.